# Group using Sunspot/Solr?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I'm having some problem searching by group when using Sunspot.

Here is an example:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: movies
#
#  id              :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  title           :string(255)

class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :actors

  searchable do
    text :title

    integer :ages, multiple: true do
      actors.map(&:age)
    end

    text :names, multiple: true do
      actors.map(&:name)
    end
  end
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: actors
#
#  id              :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  age             :integer(30)

class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :movies

  searchable do
    integer :age
    text :name
  end
end
```

I want to find every movie that has an actor named John at age 30.

```
Movie.search do
  with(:names).equal_to("John")
  with(:ages).equal_to(30)
  with(:title).equal_to("...")
  # ...
end
```

The problem is here that it may find a movie that has two actors; one named John and one at age 30. Is there a way to somehow group this together so that the movie found have an actor named John at age 30?

Comment: You have an option in your config file that controlls how your conditions form the "where" clause using `OR` or `AND` (modify it to AND to obtain what you want)

Comment: @Octopus-Paul That isn't the problem. I can use the `all_of` block to achieve what you're talking about. The problem is that one movie can have more then one actors, which means that it may find a movie with an actor at age 30 and another one named John.

Comment: You're searching at the wrong place, you should be searching for actors, as you're trying to find actors and not movies. Make your actor model searchable by solr and search on it.

Comment: @Maurício Linhares I'm not sure what I'm suppose to do with a bunch of actors. In the end I still need a list of movies.

Comment: Think with me, you want to find all movies what have actors that are aged at 30 and called John. If you find one actor at 30 and called John, **all his movies match your criteria**.

Comment: @Maurício Linhares Yes, that may be the case. But what happens if there is 4k actors that matches my search, each actor then belongs to the same movie. Then the user must scroll through 4k equal movies. I somehow need to filter out duplicate movies. I don't want the same movie to a apear more then once, even if there is two actors on the same movie who's name is John. This is one of the reasons I used the movie class instead of the actors class.

Comment: Maurício should post his solution as an answer so I can vote for it. @Oleander: Solr 3.3 supports [field collapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing) for exactly that problem, though I'm not sure how well Sunspot will handle it out of the box.

Comment: Oleander, just facet on movies when searching for the actors.

Comment: @Maurício Linhares I tried using facet, but it did't work. I also tried using Solr 3.3 that supports grouping, but that did't work either. I finally switch over to Sphinx, [which wasn't easy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058338/relation-wont-index).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution, just like [Maurício Linhares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/293686/mauricio-linhares) wrote in his comment, is to go through the actors model and group by movies.

The problem is that Sunspot doesn't support Solr 3.3 or 4.0, which is the only Solr versions that support grouping.

Here is my solution using Sunspot 1.2.1 and Solr 3.3.

*In my example `movie_id` is placed in the actors table, this isn't done in my real application.*

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: actors
#
#  id              :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime
#  movie_id        :integer(4)
#

class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable do

    # We need to store the movie_id as an string
    # So it can be sorted. We also need to pass the
    # stored: true params
    string :movie_id, stored: true do
      movie_id.to_s
    end
  end

  def search_using_solr
    scoped = Sunspot.new_search(Actor)

    scoped.build do      
      adjust_solr_params do |params|
        params[:group]          = true
        params[:"group.field"]  = "movie_id_s"
        params[:"group.format"] = "simple"
      end
    end

    # Sunspot 1.2.1 doesn't support grouping, so we need to do some hacking.
    def scoped.hits
      @hits ||= @solr_result["grouped"].values.first["doclist"]["docs"].map do |doc|
        Sunspot::Search::Hit.new(doc, nil, self)
      end
    end

    def scoped.total
      @total ||= @solr_result["grouped"]["movie_id_s"]["matches"] || 0
    end

    # Here we'll only fetch the stored data from Solr it self, 
    # and then pass it manualy to ActiveRecord.
    Movie.where({
      id: scoped.execute.hits.map{ |h| h.stored(:movie_id) }
    })
  end
end
```

Cred to [alindeman](https://github.com/alindeman) for his [example gist](https://gist.github.com/f987013b2feec5b28456).