# Relation won't index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm having some problem indexing one of my models.

Here is my model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  define_index do
    # ...
    has tracker.open, as: :open, type: :boolean
    has source.priority, as: :priority, type: :integer
    # ...
  end

  belongs_to :tracker
  belongs_to :source
end
```

I'm running this to index the model:

```
rake thinking_sphinx:index --trace
```

Here is the error:

```
undefined method `priority' for #<ThinkingSphinx::Source:0x00000106ae1738>
```

Anyone knows why the `tracker` relations works, but not the `source`?
I'm using Sphinx 0.9.9-release, Rails 3.1.0.rc5 in OS X 10.7.

**Update**

I don't get any errors during the indexing-part when using this rake task (*reindex* instead of *index*).

```
rake thinking_sphinx:reindex
```

The problem is now that I can't use the priority field.
This is the code used when searching:

```
Model.search(with: {priority: [1]})
```

This line of code:

```
has source(:priority)
```

Results in this error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) # Produced by the line above.
```

Using this line:

```
has source.priority
```

Results in this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `priority' for #<ThinkingSphinx::Source:0x00000106b0ff98>
```

Anyone knows why?

**Update 2**

Used `rake thinking_sphinx:rebuild` to reindex the database, instead of `rake thinking_sphinx:index` and `rake thinking_sphinx:reindex`.

Comment: Looks like Thinking-Sphinx have `Source` class, you have `Source` model and TS can't resolve this. Try `has source(:priority)` ...

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it did't work. I updated my post.

Comment: try to rename your `Source` model. TS has his own `source` method (http://rubydoc.info/gems/thinking-sphinx/2.0.5/ThinkingSphinx/Join:source)

Comment: I wouldn't rename the model just for something small like this, but rename the association to avoid namespace collisions: `belongs_to :source_thingy, :class_name => "Source"`

Comment: @David Grayson The problem is that sphinx isn't using ActiveRecord to index the database. It's (according to the manual) talking directly to the database. The error I'm getting is now `ERROR: index 'model_core': sql_range_query: Unknown column 'model.thingy_id' in 'on clause'` :( Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on the list, you need to use the `assoc` method to work around this:

```
has assoc(:source).priority
```

The issue here is that under the hood, Sphinx indices have sources - and so Thinking Sphinx is constructing sources automatically, hence the reserved source method. I really should change that, but this will get you around it in the meantime.